# Any way to search zlib-compressed text?

Tags: python, zlib

For a project I have to store a great deal of text and I was hoping to keep the database size small by zlib-compressing the text. Is there a way to search zlib-compressed text by testing for substrings without decompressing?

I would like to do something like the following:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> lorem = zlib.compress("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
>>> test_string = zlib.compress("Lorem")
>>> test_string in lorem
False
```

Comment: No, de-compression is indispensable to locate substrings in compressed text in the general case.  Best you can do is make a `decompressobj` to decompress and search incrementally, but that's tricky to program as the end of a decompressed part may match a **prefix** of what you're looking for and you need to carefully keep track of that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You cannot compress a short string and expect to find the result of that compression in the compressed version of a file that contains that original short string.  Compression codes the data differently depending on the data that precedes it.  In fact, that's how most compressors work -- by using the preceding data for matching strings and statistical distributions.

To search for a string, you have to decompress the data.  You do not have to store the decompressed data though.  You can read in the compressed data and decompress on the fly, discarding that data as you go until you find your string or get to the end.  If the compressed data is very large and on slow mass media, this may be faster than searching for the string in the same data uncompressed on the same media.